# How to create a CSV-File for a dataframe with multiple lists in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, export-to-csv

As I'm dealing with a huge dataset I had to split my data into different buckets. Thus, I want to save some interim results in a csv to recall it later. However, my datafile contains some columns with lists, which according to R can not be exported (see snapshot). Do you guys know a simple way for a R newbie to make this work?

Thank you so much!

[image: Snapshot of dataset]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post image of data or code.

Comment: Instead of CSV, use the `.rdata` file format with `save(...)` or `saveRDS(...)`. There's no need to parse anything, it's the fastest (or among the fastest) for write/read performance in data for R, and it preserves (nearly perfectly) the classes, attributes, and structure of the object. It doesn't matter if it's a frame with list-columns or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way to solve your problem is switching to a more apropriate file format. I recomend using write_rds() from the `readr` package, which creates [.rds files](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata). The files you create with readr::write_rds('your_file_path') can be read in with readr::read_rds('your_file_path').

The base R functions are saveRDS() and readRDS() and the functions mentioned earlier form the `readr` are just wrappers with some convience features.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click, then choose new csv to the folder where you want to save your work. Then set the separator of the csv to a comma.

Input all data in column form. You can later make it a matrix in your R program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).